# Why Does Meteor Spacebars #each Tag Not Render Content?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, spacebars, meteor-helper

The {{name}} in the below html does not inject anything into the page when it should say "hello world".  I have even tried to remove the {{name}} and put in something as simple as "blah blah blah".  The page however does not show the text.

One error I am getting is: :1039:17: #each requires an argument (compiling raffler.html)

raffler.html

```
<head>
  <title>Raffler</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">{{> raffle}}</div>
</body>

<template name="raffle">
  <h1>Raffler</h1>

  <ul id="entries">
    {{#each entries}}
      <li> {{name}} </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
 </template>
```

raffler.coffee

```
if Meteor.is_client
  Template.raffle.entries = [{name: "hello world"}]
```

Also I am working off of this tutorial: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/351-a-look-at-meteor

Comment: You're missing a closing template tag, but I don't think  that's the problem. Have you tried printing out the contents of `entries` to see if it's getting set properly?

Comment: This code works fine apart from the missing `</template>`.

Comment: the closing template was there, it was just not properly formatted in stack overflow so it did not display.  the {{#each}} tag appears to be the problem.  for example if I put <li> blah blah </li> in there it still does not work.  But if I remove the {{#each entries}}, the blah blah shows.   Even after I copy and paste directly from the correct tutorial versions github it still does not work.  This makes me think that it something wrong with my setup and I need to add something first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, maybe you missed the `</template>`, also try this:

```
if Meteor.is_client
  Template.raffle.entries = ->
    [name: "hello world"]
```

again not sure if it'll help your code looks quite ok

Comment: the closing template was there, it was just not properly formatted in stack overflow so it did not display.  the {{#each}} tag appears to be the problem.  for example if I put <li> blah blah </li> in there it still does not work.  But if I remove the {{#each entries}}, the blah blah shows.   Even after I copy and paste directly from the correct tutorial versions github it still does not work.  This makes me think that it something wrong with my setup and I need to add something first.

Comment: @SeanL I think i know what it is, use `Meteor.isClient` instead of `Meteor.is_client`. This has been updated since.

Comment: Thank you, I believe that fixed it if you want to update the answer for others ill check it